# Get the reference to the class object of an anonymous inner class

Tags: java, anonymous-class

How do you get the reference to the class object of an anonymous inner class in Java?

With non-anonimous class it is done with `ClassName.class`.

Comment: What's a reference of an anonymous class? (You mean a reference to the `Class` object representing the anonymous class?)

Comment: Cane be used by `<outerclassname>.this`

Comment: Please read carefully, the OP does not want a reference *to* the outer class but *in* the outer class.

Comment: Aren't anonymous classes interfaces implemented inline? Like Interface i = new Interface() { //class impl goes here}; therefore you already have a reference when you create them.

Comment: I bet this was a part of some conversation. Put out of the context it's very unclear what he wanted from you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If for reference to the anonymous you ask a reference to the anonymous class, the `java.lang.Class` instance object to your anonymous class here is how you can do that.

If you assign the anonimous class instance to the variable `obj` you can have a reference to the class with `obj.getClass()`. The example uses `Object`, but any non-`final` class and any interface can be used.

```
Object obj = new Object() {

};

obj.getClass(); // Reference to the anonymous class
```

You can do the same also without explicitly creating a variable like obj for example

```
Button b = ...;
b.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
    ....
}); 

ActionListener[] listeners = b.getActionListeners();
for (ActionListener listener : listeners) {
    System.out.println(listener.getClass());  // Prints the reference to the class
}
```

If no reference to the an object of type 'Anonymous' can be used (at least with reflection) you can't do that.

Comment: what is `Anonymous` ? I dont see it in JDK javadoc

Comment: Anonymous is any interface... here is only a name... can be Runnable, Collection, List or what you like

Comment: I edit the answer to be more precise

Comment: @DavideLorenzoMARINO please explain me "If no reference to the an object of type 'Anonymous' can be used (at least with reflection) you can't do that."  , so i can accept your answer

Comment: @sharonbn please check java doc https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/anonymousclasses.html

Comment: Simply doing new Anonymous () {} without assigning it and without using it as a parameter in method call

Comment: Not only an interface can be used to make an anonimous class. Any non-`final` class fits. So the `Anonimous` should be replaced with `new Object() {...}`, which is not confusing and enough to demonstrate anonimous class declaration.

Comment: @LMK, this is not javadoc (not java doc, javadoc), this is tutorial. There is no such thing as java.lang.Annonymous

Comment: What about `new ActionListener(){public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){this.getClass();}}`? :D